# Capture an event from multiple independent user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

Supposing I have a user control that exposes an update event, something like this:

```
Aspx:

    ProductFilter1.FilterChanged += new EventHandler(ProductFilter_FilterChanged);

UserControl:        

    public event EventHandler FilterChanged;

    protected void HiddenFieldFilter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FilterChanged.IsNotNull()) FilterChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

I can capture the event on the page and do something else if I choose.

However, if I have multiple occurrances of the usercontrol, say, as in a button, I might want to "do something" if any of the buttons are clicked.

How can I achieve this without creating multiple handlers on the page for the same type of control?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can point multiple events at the same handler.  You'll even know which control triggered the event by inspecting the `sender`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would still need to add ProductFilter1.FilterChanged += ..., ProductFilter2.FilterChanged += ... etc

Comment: Yes, are you saying you want one line of code to associate an event of all controls of a specific type to the same handler?

Comment: That would be ideal. Take this scenario - I have a product - a product can have several buttons that are used to do something before leaving the site (the same thing), so I jst want to capture the fact that any button has been clicked, so that the relevant updates can be performed.

Comment: Something like `Controls.OfType<UserControl>().ForEach(uc=>uc.FilterChanged += ...);`?